# Why does this solution to the "queens" dilemma run so much slower than the other in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, recursion

In my computer science class we were using Haskell to solve the "queens" problem in which you must find all possible placements of n queens in an nxn board.  This was the code we were given:

```
queens n = solve n
    where
        solve 0 = [ [] ]
        solve k = [ h:partial | partial <- solve(k-1), h <- [0..(n-1)], safe h partial ]
        safe h partial = and [ not (checks h partial i) | i <- [0..(length partial)-1] ]
        checks h partial i = h == partial!!i || abs(h-partial!!i) == i+1
```

However, the first time I entered it I accidentally swapped the order in solve k and found that it still gave a correct solution but took much longer:

```
queens n = solve n
where
    solve 0 = [ [] ]
    solve k = [ h:partial | h <- [0..(n-1)], partial <- solve(k-1), safe h partial ]
    safe h partial = and [ not (checks h partial i) | i <- [0..(length partial)-1] ]
    checks h partial i = h == partial!!i || abs(h-partial!!i) == i+1
```

Why does this second version take so much longer?  My thought process is that the second version does recursion at every step while the first version does recursion only once and then backtracks.  This is not for a homework problem, I'm just curious and feel like it will help me better understand the language.

Comment: The real question is where is this class and why isn't it using SBV?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply put,

```
[ ... | x <- f 42, n <- [1..100] ]
```

will evaluate `f 42` once to a list, and for each element `x` in such list it will generate all `n`s from `1` to `100`. Instead,

```
[ ... | n <- [1..100], x <- f 42 ]
```

will first generate an `n` from `1` to `100`, and for each of them call `f 42`. So `f` is now being called 100 times instead of one.

This is no different from what happens in imperative programming when using nested loops:

```py
for x in f(42):    # calls f once
   for n in range(1,100): 
      ...
for n in range(1,100): 
   for x in f(42): # calls f 100 times
      ...
```

The fact that your algorithm is recursive makes this swap particularly expensive, since the additional cost factor (100, above) accumulates at each recursive call.

You can also try to bind the result of `f 42` to some variable so that it does not need to be recomputed, even if you nest it the other way around:

```
[ ... | let xs = f 42, n <- [1..100], x <- xs ]
```

Note that this will keep the whole `xs` list in memory for the whole loop, preventing it from being garbage collected. Indeed, `xs` will be fully evaluated for `n=1`, and then reused for higher values of `n`.

Comment: Thank you! This was the answer I was looking for in simple enough terms that I could understand.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that your first version does a depth-first traversal while your second version does a breadth-first traversal of the tree ([see Tree Traversal on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal)).

As the complexity of the problem grows with the size of the board, the second version uses more and more memory to keep track of each level of the tree while the first version quickly forgets the previous branch it visited.

Managing the memory takes a lot of time!

By [enabling profiling](https://nikita-volkov.github.io/profiling-cabal-projects/), you can see how the Haskell runtime behaves with your functions.

If you compare the number of calls, they are strictly the same, but still the second version takes more time:

```
COST CENTRE          MODULE                  no.     entries  %time %alloc   %time %alloc

MAIN                 MAIN                     44           0    0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0
 main                Main                     89           0    0.3    0.0     0.3    0.0
 CAF                 Main                     87           0    0.0    0.0    99.7  100.0
  main               Main                     88           1    0.2    0.6    99.7  100.0
   queens2           Main                     94           1    0.0    0.0    55.6   48.2
    queens2.solve    Main                     95          13    3.2    0.8    55.6   48.2
     queens2.safe    Main                     96    10103868   42.1   47.5    52.3   47.5
      queens2.checks Main                    100    37512342   10.2    0.0    10.2    0.0
   queens1           Main                     90           1    0.0    0.0    43.9   51.1
    queens1.solve    Main                     91          13    2.0    1.6    43.9   51.1
     queens1.safe    Main                     92    10103868   29.3   49.5    41.9   49.5
      queens1.checks Main                     93    37512342   12.7    0.0    12.7    0.0
```

Looking at the heap profile tells you what really happens.

The first version has a small and constant heap use:

[image]

While the second version has a huge heap use which must also face garbage collection (look at the peaks):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the core, the first function generates a *single* function in core, which is tail recursive (constant stack space - very fast and very nice function. Thanks GHC!). However, the 2nd generates *two* functions: one to do a single step of the inner loop; and a 2nd function which looks like

`loop x = case x of { 0 -> someDefault; _ -> do1 (loop (x-1)) }`

This function likely isn't performant because `do1` must traverse the entire input list, and each iteration appends new elements to the list (meaning the input list to `do1` grows monotonically in length). Whereas the core function for the fast version is generating the output list directly, without having to process some other list. It is quite difficult to reason about the performance of list comprehension, I believe, so first translate the function to not use them:

```
guard b = if b then [()] else [] 

solve_good k = 
          concatMap (\partial -> 
          concatMap (\h -> 
          guard (safe h partial) >> return (h:partial)
           ) [0..n-1]
           ) (solve $ k-1)

solve_bad k = 
          concatMap (\h -> 
          concatMap (\partial -> 
          guard (safe h partial) >> return (h:partial)
           ) (solve $ k-1)
           ) [0..n-1]
```

The transformation is fairly mechanical and is detailed somewhere in the Haskell report, but essentially `<-` becomes `concatMap` and conditions become `guard`s. It is much easier to see what is happening now - `solve_good` makes a recursive call a single time, then `concatMap`s over that recursively created list. However, `solve_bad` makes the recursive call *inside* the outer `concatMap`, meaning it will potentially (likely) be recomputed for every element in `[0..n-1]`. Note that there is no *semantic* reason for `solve $ k-1` to be in the inner `concatMap` - it does not depend on the value that that concatMap binds (the `h` variable) so it can be safely lifted out above the concatMap which binds `h` (as is done in `solve_good`).